# Magento Programmatically Re-Authorize Orders

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-gateway, authorize.net

We recently had a major issue in our installation of Magento, over 500 orders were placed and successfully authorized, but did not save their information in the `additional_information` field in the table `sales_flat_order_payment`.

As such, when we try to capture the payment via authorize.net, it sends all null values to them. They return the response "invalid expiration date".

What I need to do is re-authorize (NOT capture) all of these orders programatically. How would one go about this without creating new orders?

Would re-authorizing orders even fix this?

Is there a way to programatically make the `additional_information` column not have a null value?